# How to hide all other divs when one div show?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is the site : **http://test.slatong.com/**

In the header menu. When you hover each list item, it will show different div#id.

I want to know how to hide all other divs when one another div showing in the header like this site : **http://www.hytwatches.com/**

I am still trying to find the way.

HERE IS THE CODE I WROTE:

```
<div id="slidemenu">
          <!---  HEADER -->
          <header class="top-header">

            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">

                <nav class="main-navigation">

                  <ul class="menu col-lg-10" >
                    <li data-file="about">
                      <a href="" class="item col-lg-2">
                        about us
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-file="collection">
                      <a href="" class="item col-lg-2">
                        collection
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="logo">
                      <a href="" class="middle col-lg-2">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-file="innovation">
                      <a href="" class="item col-lg-2">
                        innovation
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-file="find-us">
                      <a href="" class="item col-lg-2">
                        find us
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>

                  <div class="socials col-lg-2">

                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href="" class="facebook">
                          f
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="" class="twitter">
                          t
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="" class="youtube">
                          y
                        </a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>

                  </div>
                  <!---  socials -->

                </nav>
                <!---  end main navigation -->

              </div>
              <!---  end row -->
            </div>
            <!---  end container -->

          </header>
          <!---  end top header -->



          <!--- SUB MENU SECTION -->
          <section>

            <div id="sub_menu">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <nav>
                <ul class="dspn"  id="about">
                  <li class="col-lg-3">
                    <a href="">
                      <img src="img/about/about-behind_hyt.png" >
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="col-lg-3">
                    <a href="">
                      <img src="img/about/about-behind_hyt.png" >
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="col-lg-3">
                    <a href="">
                      <img src="img/about/about-behind_hyt.png" >
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="col-lg-3">
                    <a href="http://www.hytwatches.com/Services/PressMedia.sls" >
                      <img src="img/about/about-behind_hyt.png" >
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                </nav>



                <nav>
                <ul class="dspn" id="innovation">
                  <li class="col-lg-3">
                    <a href="http://www.hytwatches.com/Innovation/HYTScience.sls">
                      <img src="img/about/about-behind_hyt.png" >
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="col-lg-3">
                    <a href="http://www.hytwatches.com/Innovation/HYTnnovation.sls">
                      <img src="img/about/about-behind_hyt.png" >
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="col-lg-3">
                    <a href="http://guide.hytwatches.com">
                      <img src="img/about/about-behind_hyt.png" >
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                </nav>

                <nav>
                <ul class="dspn" id="find-us">
                  <li class="col-lg-3">
                    <a href="http://www.hytwatches.com/Services/CustomerService.sls" >
                      <img src="img/about/about-behind_hyt.png" >
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="col-lg-3">
                    <a href="http://www.hytwatches.com/Services/ContactHYT.sls" >
                      <img src="img/about/about-behind_hyt.png" >
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="col-lg-3">
                    <a href="http://www.hytwatches.com/Services/Retails.sls">
                      <img src="img/about/about-behind_hyt.png" >
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="col-lg-3">
                    <a href="http://lounge.hytwatches.com">
                      <img src="img/about/about-behind_hyt.png" >
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                </nav>

             </div>
             </div>
            </div>


          </section>
          <!---  end sub menu section -->
```

HERE IS JQUERY CODE :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id = $(".main-navigation ul li").data("file");
        $("#sub_menu  nav ul#" + id).addClass("dspn");

});
```

Comment: please share your javascript code

Comment: Have you made any attempts at this yourself so far? SO is not a site to come and request code, but rather request help troubleshooting code you already have. Also, it is preferred that you include the problem code in your post rather than linking to an external site. Once the problem is resolved, the external site will no longer be useful as a reference to others down the road.

Comment: Sorry for that, I just rewrote my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".main-navigation ul li").each(function () {
        var id = $(this).data("file");
        $("#" + id).addClass("dspn");
    });
    $(".main-navigation ul li").on("mouseenter", function (e) {
        var id = $(this).data("file");
        var $target = $("#" + id).stop(true).slideDown();
        clearTimeout($target.data('hoverTimer'));
    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
        var id = $(this).data("file");
        var $target = $("#" + id);
        var timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $target.stop(true).slideUp();
        }, 200);
        $target.data('hoverTimer', timer);
    });

    $('#sub_menu .dspn').hover(function () {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimer'));
    }, function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $this.stop(true).slideUp();
        }, 200);
        $this.data('hoverTimer', timer);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li data="one">home</li>
    <li data="two">about us</li>
</ul>
<div data="one" class="hide">1</div>
<div data="two" class="hide">2</div>
<script>
    $('li').mouseover(function(){
        var data = $(this).attr("data");
        $('div[data]').each(function(){
            var innerData = $(this).attr("data");
            if(innerData == data){
                $(this).addClass('display');
                $(this).removeClass('hide');
            }else{
                $(this).addClass('hide');
                $(this).removeClass('display');
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

u can use above piece of code.
CSS:

```
    .hide{
        display: none;
    }
    .display{
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: and yes don't forget to add jquery library. :)